# QSqlQuery prepared statements - proper usage

Tags: sql, qt, prepared-statement

I'm trying to determine the proper way to use prepared statements with QSqlQuery. The docs are not very specific on this subject.

```
void select(const QSqlDatabase &database) {
    QSqlQuery query(database);
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM theUniverse WHERE planet = :planet");
    query.bindValue(":planet", "earth");
    query.exec();
}
```

So will this snippet create a permanent prepared statement in the connection `database`? Will this prepared statement persist between calls to `select()`, i.e. will it be saved when the function returns and `QSqlQuery query` is disposed?

Or should I create QSqlQuery on the heap and use the same instance over and over again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the idea is that you have to create QSqlQuery on heap, prepare the query and do the following with it:

1. `QSqlQuery::bindValue(s)`
2. `QSqlQuery::exec`
3. read data with `QSqlQuery::[next|first|last|...]`
4. `QSqlQuery::finish`
5. rinse and repeat

the following snipped is useful to create, prepare and retrieve queries on heap:

```
QSqlDatabase database;
QMap<QString, QSqlQuery *> queries; //dont forget to delete them later!

QSqlQuery *prepareQuery(const QString &query)
{
    QSqlQuery *ret = 0;
        if (!queries.contains(query)) {
            QSqlQuery *q = new QSqlQuery(database);
            q->prepare(query);
            queries[query] = ret = q;
        } else {
            ret = queries[query];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```